# Which is correct? (both .. and)

Tags: grammar

Rewrite the following sentence by using "both .. and".

Peter is a naughty boy. He is an active boy.

1. Peter is both naughty and active.
2. Peter is both a naughty boy and an active one.
3. Peter is both a naughty and active boy.
4. Peter is both a naughty and an active boy.

Comment: I think the first one is correct but I'm not sure about the other three sentences though.

Answer (score 1):

They all appear correct. 4 seems to read better than 3, as the *an* balances out the previous *a* .

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the examples found [here](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/conj-paired.html), it is best to make sure that the words which *both* applies to are [parallelly structured](http://www.evergreen.edu/writingcenter/handouts/grammar/parallel.pdf). By this reasoning, your first, second, and fourth examples are correct. The third is technically incorrect, although it is perfectly intelligible and not at all uncommon.

Here's what I mean:

> 1. both *naughty* and *active*
> 2. both *a naughty boy* and *an active one*
> 3. both *a naughty* and *active* boy
> 4. both *a naughty* and *an active* boy

The constructions are parallel in each example but the third, in which *a naughty* does not correspond to *active*.

Bear in mind that you could also say the following:

> Peter is a naughty, active boy.